# ChangeDetectorRef with events. I get ViewDestroyed Error

Tags: angular

I am running into this error

> ViewDestroyedError: Attempt to use a destroyed view: detectChanges

when I am calling `ChangeDetectorRef.DetectChanges()` from an event. I have been stumped on this for almost 2 days now and I just cannot figure it out.

Okay, I have created a small sample to demonstrate what is going on. we have 3 different modules. On called `shared.module.ts` The other two really don't matter what they're called, but just for your information they are called `crm.module.ts` and `admin.module.ts`.

What it is important here, is that `SharedModule` has something called `SidebarService` in its providers. The SidebarService looks something like:

```
@Injectable()
export class SidebarService {

    viewChanged:EventEmitter<any>=new EventEmitter<any>();

    //other properties and methods here

    viewClick(view:SidebarView):void{
        this.selectedView = view;
        this.viewChanged.emit(view);
    }
}
```

Now in the other two module I have a main component that subscribes to this event. Something like:

```
ngOnInit():void{
    this.sidebarService.selectedView = this.views[0];
    this.sidebarService.views = this.views;
    this.sidebarService.visible = true;


    this.sidebarService.viewChanged.subscribe(view=>{
        this.changeDetectorRef.detectChanges();
    });
}
```

Okay, so now to the funny business... it doesnt throw this error when i switch to the main view of the other module, only when I switch child view in that module.

**What I have tried...**
I have tried to `onDestroy()`

1. unsubscribe from viewChanges event
2. detach from changeDetector
3. detach then unsubscribe
4. unsubscribe then detach

Non of this worked and I am still getting the error.

I created a plnkr.co that was able to recreate this but for some reason it didn't save. If it is needed by someone here, I will do this again.

Comment: What code did you use to unsub or detach from the change detector?

Comment: Have you tried using `changeDetectorRef.markForCheck()` instead of `detectChanges?` `markForCheck` merely inserts the component into the change detection cycle while `detectChanges` actually runs change detection each time it's called. You could just `markForCheck` in child components and then run `detectChanges` from the service to run detection for all children, regardless if their view still exists or not.

Comment: Thank you @joh04667, that lead me in correct direction. After making the changes that you spoke of. i ran into a ChangeDetectorRef has no Provider error. I then found this link
 https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/14656 which finished off the console errors. So again, thank you for your time.